# I have many cousins but no siblings :(

Tags: riddle

Born insomniac, I'm always running

When I'm absent my friend watches over Elle Fanning

If you want to feel joy you can stand on my head

Cause I'm the happiest person you'll ever meet, rarely sad.

Comment: "j+o+y" is very close to "y-o-u" on its head, especially in Latin, where j = i = y

Comment: @humn nahhhhh!!

Comment: (And y = u, sorry to leave that out. Doesn't matter, I knew it was a false lead.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you:

> **The Moon?**

Born insomniac, I'm always running

> **The Moon** is up all night, and it's always moving in orbit.

When I'm absent my friend watches over Elle Fanning

> Your friend is The Sun. I'm guessing this is reference to Elle playing Aurora in Maleficent? An Aurora (like The Northern Lights) is caused/affected by solar winds from The Sun.

If you want to feel joy you can stand on my head

> Over **The Moon** is a common phrase for saying you are happy or feeling joy.

Cause I'm the happiest person you'll ever meet, rarely sad.

> This comes from the saying **Once In A Blue Moon** If you are sad, you may be referred to as 'blue'

Title: I have many cousins but no siblings :(

> **The Moon's** 'cousins' are other Moons, but The Earth only has one Moon, so no 'siblings'.